# firebase warnings - there is a way to catch them in js code?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using firebase (for angular) and sometimes I got 
`@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: The Firebase database '---' has exceeded its quota limit and has been temporarily disabled. See https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#database-overquota for more information`

printed to console as a warning (from their npm module)
I want to catch it in order to display fallback results. Can I do it? this is just a warning, not an error.
I want to do something like this:

```
try{
//read from firebase
} catch(err){
//read from local storage
}
```

Comment: Not certain about catching an error, but it looks like you can use the Google Cloud Monitoring API to see your quota usage, and detect if it has been exceeded.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual code that's generating the error, and explain what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: this is `console.warn` that Firebase library print and I want to catch it on code